# How to add background Color to List in swiftUI

Tags: swiftui-list, swiftui

I want to change the background white to an another color to the List in SwiftUI

[image: Click Here]

```
List(listOfItems) { item in
    Group {
        HStack {
            item.iconImage.padding()
            Text(item.text).fontWeight(.regular).foregroundColor(Color("smalltext")).font(.system(size: 25))
            Spacer()
            Button(action: {
                
            }) {
                Image("back")
            }
        }.padding().background(Color("bg"))
    }.listRowBackground(Color("bg"))
}.background(Color("bg"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to change the background color you would do the following in the view containing the `List`. Add this `init` block in your `View`. This will change everything to green.

```
init() {
   UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = .green
   UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .green
}
```

Comment: didnt work for me